# is there a connection between the British slate roofs and slate roofs found in the Himalayan State of India ( Uttarakhand)

Tags: india, architecture, building, colony

I was reading some basic text on Mughal architecture on Wikipedia, and I came across this image -

[image],

This is a house in the Indian Himalayan State of Uttarakhand, here is the second Image -

[image: image 2]

which is a British House

There might be some connection here ( not saying there is, just asking if there is), between these two, as Uttarakhand was the summer capital of British colonial officers.

I don't have much architectural history of Uttarakhand, and I have nothing before British rule, But again there are traditional temples that have similar styles of roofs like in Jageshware Temple in Almora.

Roofing tiles are prevalent in most of India, mostly for style, but they probably were not before colonial rule, I think considering it a Himalayan state, snow and rain are common issues, maybe they used it for a long time even before the arrival of the British. Their ( Indian)  style of putting them looks rawer in this image, but this is probably due to the availability of rock, they used whatever they got, instead of finding equal parts.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Presumably there was a nearby source of slate in both places?

Answer (score 10):

[An article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12371-020-00487-y) on Himachal slate gives multiple examples of temples (such as [Chandrashekhar Temple](https://www.hindu-blog.com/2021/04/chandrashekhar-temple-at-saho-village-chamba-himachal-pradesh.html) among others) with slate roofs from the 10th-century onwards. It also mentions that in certain areas slate is used today in almost every building, not only as roofing but also for flooring, fencing, and cladding. While I won't rule out the possibility that the first photo may exhibit some vague colonial architectural influence, it is clear that the geological abundance of local slate resources and their inherent usefulness for roofing was recognized long before the British arrived.

Comment: So... the British got slate roofs from India?

Comment: @Astor: the people in Britain and the people in India might have independently from each other realized, that slate or any other thin slabs of stone makes for a good roofing material.

Comment: @DohnJoe Please put that in an answer with citations